# MySQL Error Code: 1064 Stored Procedure Syntax Error near END END

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I am Fairly new at the MYSQL programming, I need to create a Stored Procedure that adds an animal to the Animal Table, But it needs to check that the Foreign keys exist in the Catagory table (catID) and the Area Table (areaID).

This is what I have so far, but getting an error message that says there is a syntax error near END END, I have tried putting brackets but then there are just more errors.

If any one can help that would be great!

```
-- checking if the SP already exists and deletes it
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_AddAnimal;

-- creates the stored procedure to add animals to the Animal Table
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_AddAnimal
        (
        IN  p_animalType                    VARCHAR(30), 
        IN  p_weight                        VARCHAR(6) , 
        IN  p_gender                        VARCHAR(7) , 
        IN  p_age                           VARCHAR(4) , 
        IN  p_stock                         INT        , 
        IN  p_catID                         INT        ,
        IN  p_areaID                        INT      
     )
BEGIN 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT catID FROM Catagory WHERE Catagory.catID = p_catID) THEN
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT areaID FROM Area WHERE Area.areaID = p_areaID) THEN
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Animal
                    (
                        animalType                    , 
                        weight                        , 
                        gender                        , 
                        age                           , 
                        stock                         , 
                        catID                         ,
                        areaID                        
                    )
                VALUES 
                    ( 
                        p_animalType                    , 
                        p_weight                        , 
                        p_gender                        , 
                        p_age                           , 
                        p_stock                         , 
                        p_catID                         , 
                        p_areaID                    
                    ) ; 
            END
    END   
END 

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: For IF statements, use END IF;
Also, don't forget semicolons.

Comment: [*This documentation*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) might help you out if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `IF ... END IF` blocks is:

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

From the [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) in the comments.
You need to use `END IF` instead of just `END` to close your

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT catID FROM Catagory WHERE Catagory.catID = p_catID) THEN
```

and your

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT areaID FROM Area WHERE Area.areaID = p_areaID) THEN
```